# mySQL - Count of Customers

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure how to do this query to display a count of customers each sales rep has worked with.
I'm working with my 'Rep' entity/table. 
The columns in that table include: cust_id, rep_num, rep_id and quota. But I'm only working on trying to get the count of customers a rep has worked with.

My query:

```
SELECT count(cust_id), rep_num
FROM rep
```

Right above, it only shows one rep and counted all the customers in that table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to group them by the representative id.

```
SELECT count(cust_id) AS customers_count, rep_num
FROM rep GROUP BY rep_id
```